# Argparse: get all options passed in command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I am using Argparse library in python and required to retrieve all the options passed at the time of invoking. For example, if given program expects three command line parameters:

```
parser.add_argument('-a', action="store_true", default=False)
parser.add_argument('-b', action="store", dest="b")
parser.add_argument('-c', action="store", dest="c", type=int)
```

So if I call `python test.py -b`
I need a way to know that -b was passed as command line option.

In old optparse this can be done by overriding optparse.Option but I am unable to find its equivalent in argparse

Comment: Does it work? If not, what happens?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, and why argparse is not doing what you need. Can you please make a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Do you have an example of the output you except?

Comment: Elaborate on what you can do in `optparse`.

Answer (score 4):

Just test for the default value set, like the *default* default value `None`:

```
if args.b is None:
    # -b was not used
```

This won't work for `-a` as `store_true` implies a default `False`. You can tell `argparse` to use `None` as the default instead:

```
parser.add_argument('-a', action="store_true", default=None)
```

but since you cannot use `-a` and have `not args.a` be true, you can just test for *that* default still:

```
parser.add_argument('-a', action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
if not args.a:
    # -a was not used
```

If `None` is to be a valid choice (say, you use `action="store_const", const=None`) use a different sentinel for the default:

```
_sentinel = object()
parser.add_argument('-d', action="store_const",
                    const=None, default=_sentinel)
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.d is _sentinel():
    # -d was not used
```

You can also prevent a default from being set *altogether*, by setting the default to `argparse.SUPPRESS`:

```
parser.add_argument('-e', default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
args = parser.parse_args()
if not hasattr(args, 'e'):
    # -e was not used
```

You can list all optional actions actually used used by looping over `parser._optionals._actions` and seeing if their `.dest` attribute is present and not set to the `.default` value:

```
used_options = [
    action for action in parser._optionals._actions
    if getattr(args, action.dest, action.default) is not action.default]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-a', action="store_true", default=False)
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['-a'], dest='a', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('-b', action="store", dest="b")
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-b'], dest='b', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('-c', action="store", dest="c", type=int)
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-c'], dest='c', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=<type 'int'>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> def list_used_options(parser, args):
...     return [
...         action for action in parser._optionals._actions
...         if getattr(args, action.dest, action.default) is not action.default]
... 
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['-a'])
>>> list_used_options(parser, args)
[_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['-a'], dest='a', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)]
```

This just echoes what `sys.argv[1:]` was already telling you was passed in, of course.

Comment: I need to store all the parameters that were passed to command line in a list. Available options are long list and every option does not has default value associated with it. If you can help me for this that would be grateful

Comment: @ujjwalwahi: All command line options passed to the script are already available as a list in  `sys.argv`.

Comment: @JoelCornett: somehow I was assuming that that wasn't good enough. Having the `Action` instances can have its uses, but if the OP wanted the exact command line, then it is indeed already there for the taking.

Answer (score 0):

Checking against the defaults is the most straight forward way of checking whether an option has been given (seen).  The default default `None` is good in this regard, since you can't give `None` in the command line.  For `store_true` (or false), the default is always the opposite boolean value.  But, I realize that it isn't always convenient (or possible?) to use such a default.

`parse_args` does keep track of seen options in a variable, `seen_actions`.  It uses this set to test whether all 'required' options have been seen.  A refinement on this set, `seen_non_default_actions` is used to test required mutually exclusive groups.

But neither of these sets is available outside of `parse_args`.  I have worked on a patch that extends the concept of mutually exclusive groups.  That would provide a hook that can run tests on these `seen` sets (in the bug reports look for one with 'nest inclusive groups' in the title).